# Form 'submit button' won't SLIDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, submit-button

Would you please tell me why the slide function won't work ?

https://jsfiddle.net/lcoulon/51gn2v45/

It won't slide either into a real HTML page even i called CSS and jquery :

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/slide-submit.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My final is to integrate this submit button into a Bootstrap4 webpage template.

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: it works actually
https://jsfiddle.net/51gn2v45/2/

Comment: your libraries not included correctly, in console there were exceptions about that

Comment: Many thanks, i fixed the real HTML page as well there is no error in the console about libraries but the button still won't slide : http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/bootstrap-test/dashboard/

Comment: Wellp, have you added code for that? Because of when I copied and paste this https://i.gyazo.com/de7af06987273449b7a8254fd1bb378c.png it started to work https://i.gyazo.com/58dfd9df25cec9fc87e5f6d0c74181cd.mp4

Comment: Yes, libraries are called at the end of the HTML file but it does not work anyway. But it does so if I copy paste the code into jsfiddle...

Comment: But what about the code responsible for that? Look at the screenshot I pasted above - I just opened the console and paste code in right when I was on your website. Seems like there are no handler on your webstie client code. And better to include links on the libraries at the head part of the html file

Comment: Many thanks for your help Danil, i got it fixed.

Comment: Np, if u dont mind, I'll copy my comments to answer?

Comment: Yes, sure please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in JSfiddle example problem was with the links.
Here (after few attempts) [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/51gn2v45/2/)

Second, or your website seems like you forgot to add slider handling code.
As you said, no errors in console, so I just tried to add code directly
[image]

(Only this part above to see if it would change something)

```
    /*!
 * Slide to submit button
 */

 $(".slide-submit button").draggable({cancel: false, containment: "parent", axis: "x", stop: function() {
  if (($(this).parent().width() / 2) === ($(this).position().left + 8)) {
    $(this).css({left: "auto", right: 0}).addClass("submitted").text("Submitting...").draggable('false');
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  } else {
    $(this).css({left: 0});
  }
}}).on("click", function() {
  return false;
});
```

And it looks like it worked out ([recorded animation here](https://i.gyazo.com/58dfd9df25cec9fc87e5f6d0c74181cd.mp4))